# CPU MHz don't reach CPU min MHz in lscpu

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, clock, lscpu

I think CPU MHZ is always more than CPU min MHz.

But, my server can't do that now.

When it looks like below, what should I check?

---

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                40
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              4
```

```
CPU MHz:               172.617
CPU max MHz:           3600.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
```

```
BogoMIPS:              6001.58
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm spec_ctrl retpoline kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: It appears they are questioning why the current MHz frequency (172.617) is possibly lower than the "min MHz" frequency (1200). Primarily in the second code block.

Comment: userSeventeen is correct. why CPU MHz is lower than CPU min HMz? 
Now, server is so slow.

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1419382/1129247) out.